# Prove $|h(x)|\leq (Mx^2)/2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I repeated this question because I would really appreciate a hint.

Let $h:[0,a]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable, $h'(0)=h(0)=0$, and $|h''(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in [0,a]$.

I proceed with the mean value theorem, but I do not have the factor of $1/2$ in the result above (I get$|g(x)|\leq (Mx^2)$). Does anyone have any hints? Let me know if more detail is wanted. Is there a solution only using MVT?

Comment: please do NOT repeat questions! This is an abuse of this site. Where is the old question? If it was closed, why did you not improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define
$$
g:[0,a]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, g(x) = h(x) - M\frac{x^2}{2} \, .
$$
Then $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$ and $g''(x) \le 0$ in $[0, a]$.
Apply the MVT twice to obtain $g(x) \le 0$ in $[0, a]$.

For the other direction, use $\tilde g(x) = h(x) + M\frac{x^2}{2}$  .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use Taylor theorem with Lagrange remainder to expand $h$ at $0$:
$$h(x) = h(0) + h'(0)x + \frac{1}{2}h''(\theta x) x^2.$$
where $\theta \in (0, 1)$.

---

For any $x_0 \in (0, a]$, let $A$ be defined such that $h(x_0) = h(0) + h'(0)x_0 + Ax_0^2 = Ax_0^2$. And define 
$$g(x) = h(x) - (h(0) - h'(0)x) - Ax^2 = h(x) - Ax^2, x \in [0, x_0].$$
By condition, $g(0) = g(x_0) = 0$, hence by MVT, there exists $\xi_1 \in (0, x_0)$ such that $g'(\xi) = h'(\xi) - 2A\xi = 0$. On the other hand, $g'(0) = h'(0) - 2A\times 0 = h'(0) = 0$. So $g'(\xi) = g'(0) = 0$ and another application of MVT then gives $g''(\eta) = 0$ for some $\eta \in (0, \xi)$. Since $g''(\eta) = h''(\eta) + 2A$, we deduce that 
$$|A| = \frac{1}{2}|h''(\eta)| \leq \frac{1}{2}M,$$
which implies that 
$$|h(x_0)| = |Ax_0^2| \leq \frac{1}{2}Mx_0^2.$$

Comment: I should have mentioned we have been shown this with Taylor's method but have to use MVT. I'll edit above.

Comment: Then you essentially repeat the proof of Taylor's theorem, it might be helpful if you review the proof details of Taylor's theorem.

Comment: I don't see the connection: I know to repeatedly use MVT but I can't get the constant term.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $h(x) = \int_0^x (x-t) h''(t) dt$, then proceed by using the esgtimate for $h''$.

Comment: I am sad to say that integration is not yet available to me!

Answer (score 0):

Actually something stronger is true. We dont need $h$ twice differentiable on an interval, just that $h''(0)$ exists. Using the MVT:

$$h(x) = h(x) - h(0) = h'(c_x)x = (h'(c_x)-h'(0))x = [(h'(c_x)-h'(0))/c_x]c_x \cdot x.$$

Because $h''(0)$ exists, $[(h'(c_x)-h'(0))/c_x]$ is bounded in absolute value for small $x,$ say by $M.$ For such $x,$ $|h(x)| \le M|c_x\cdot x| \le Mx^2.$

Comment: But in the question, the goal was to show that $|h(x)| \le M x^2/2$, where $M$ is a given bound for the second derivative.

Comment: Right, I forgot the $1/2$! Thanks.